# Terraform: Return a Single occurrence of key/value in a map if the values for the same key are identical

Tags: merge, terraform

I'm looking for a way to check if the given key's value is same for two objects and only return the first object.

I have below code for example.

```
variable "my_store" {
  default = [
    {
      store_number            = 101
      store_name              = "walmart"
      store_location          = "NY"
      items                   = ["apple", "banana"]
    },
    {
      store_number            = 389
      store_name              = "walmart"
      store_location          = "TN"
      items                   = ["orange", "mango"]
    }
  ]
}
locals {
  de_duplicate = { for k, i in var.my_store : k => i if length(lookup(i, "store_name", "")) > 0  }
}
output "de_duplicate" {
  value = local.de_duplicate
}
```

Output:

```
de_duplicate = {
  "0" = {
    "items" = [
      "apple",
      "banana",
    ]
    "store_location" = "NY"
    "store_name" = "walmart"
    "store_number" = 101
  }
  "1" = {
    "items" = [
      "orange",
      "mango",
    ]
    "store_location" = "TN"
    "store_name" = "walmart"
    "store_number" = 389
  }
}
```

Expected Output:
 <strike>It doesn't matter if the other keys from the index 1 is not available because I'm only going to iterate once for any duplicate and use the key "store_name", rest of the keys are not used.</strike>

I just realized that I would need the all the key and values from the first occurrence ie., index 0

```
de_duplicate = {
  "0" = {
    "items" = [
      "apple",
      "banana",
    ]
    "store_location" = "NY"
    "store_name" = "walmart"
    "store_number" = 101
  }
}
```

OR

```
de_duplicate = {
  "0" = {
    "store_name" = "walmart"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE (but could not get all the keys from the first occurrence index 0)**

I tried the below method, this is not serving the purpose as I need all the keys & values from index 0, please let me know if you have a better and simpler alternative.

```
locals {
  de_duplicate = { for k, i in var.my_store : k => i if length(lookup(i, "store_name", "")) > 0 }
  new          = distinct([for r in local.de_duplicate : r.store_name])
  new2 = { for k, i in flatten([for n in local.new :
    {
      store_name = n
  }]) : k => i }
}
output "de_duplicate" {
  value = local.new2
}
```

Output:

```
de_duplicate = {
  "0" = {
    "store_name" = "walmart"
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current output?

Comment: @Marcin When I supply this to a for_each to create resources, since store_name value is same for two or more objects it creates multiple resources, instead I need only one resource iterated.

Comment: "ugly" is relative. If it works and does the job, why force it and look for some other code?

Comment: @Marcin Just realized that I would need all the keys and values from the first occurrence ie., 0, any suggestion please?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Does you `my_store` always contain two elements only? If not, you compare only two consecutive elements for similarity, or any combination? What happens if there are no similar objects?

Comment: `my_store` may contain any number of elements. If three elements have duplicate value for `store_name`, then only first occurrence should be returned and so on... If no similar objects found it should return as normal, as it is.